# How to send arguments to process running in the background?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, process, signals

I wrote a small shell script that plays music when ever I call it.

```
function playmusic() {
  find /music/path -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec mplayer {} \;
}
```

and added it to my `.zshrc` file, so now I can play music by calling `playmusic`.

If I am working with multiple tabs I had to search the tab where I am playing the music, but if I know how can I send arguments to `playmusic` function PID then I can control it from any terminal.

any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would this work for you?
 `find /music/path -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec mplayer -enqueue {} \;`
This will enqueue all the arguments to your current play list

Comment: yes @Allan, I got into that issue. Now I am planning to make a playlist and get songs by pattern and make a playlist features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slave mode: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt

For example:

```
mkfifo ~/.mplayer/fifo

function playmusic(){
    find /music/path -type -name "*.mp3" -exec \
    mplayer -really-quiet -slave -input file=~/.mplayer/fifo {} \;
}

function mmute(){
    echo m > ~/.mplayer/fifo
}
function mquit(){
    echo q > ~/.mplayer/fifo
}
```